# Nodal/mesh analysis problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Consider the circuit in the attached image. The task is to determine the currents in the nodes A and B. The values of the different components are given. Any hints on where to start? I’ve considered replacing the current source with a voltage source and vice versa (the current source is connected in parallel with too many resistors to keep track of, and the voltage source isn’t connected in series with any resistor), as well as replacing some of the parallel resistors, but have been unsuccessful thus far.

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with superposition and, if so, have you tried it?

Comment: I’m familiar with superposition, but superposition of what? Currents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean "find the voltages of nodes A and B".  Currents in node A and B doesn't make sense.

First, you can ignore $R_5$ since it is parallel with an ideal voltage source, $V_S$, and as such it will have zero affect on the rest of the circuit.

Now, you can use Bob D's suggestion and use superposition.  Kill the current source (by opening it) and then find the voltages from A to reference, and B to reference, produced by the voltage source $V_S$.  I would call these $V_Aˊ$ and $V_Bˊ$ where the single prime indicates the voltage produced by the first source we are considering, $V_S$.

Next, put the current source back, and kill the voltage source (by short circuiting it) and then find the same voltages - but this time call them $V_Aˊˊ$ and $V_Bˊˊ$.  You will see that since they are now shorted together they have the same value.

Finally, the resulting voltages with both sources in service will be,
$$V_A = V_Aˊ + V_Aˊˊ$$
and
$$V_B = V_Bˊ + V_Bˊˊ$$

Superposition can remarkably simplify many circuits problems.  To kill current sources you open them.  To kill voltage sources you short them out.

p.s.  The "reference" i'm referring to is the node at the very bottom (horizontal line).

**UPDATE** - showing superposition approach. The node voltages i will be finding are the voltages from the respective node to the reference (bottom of circuit).

Here is the original circuit,

[image]

First, i'll kill the voltage source (by shorting it out) and find the contribution to each nodes voltage due to the current source,

[image]

It is obvious that the currents flowing down through $R_2$ and $R_4$ have to sum to $I_S$, so we can find $V_Aˊ$ as,

$$V_Aˊ = V_Bˊ = I_S \frac{R_2R_4}{R_2+R_4}$$

Similarly, we can find $V_Cˊ$ as,

$$V_Cˊ = I_S \left(\frac{R_2R_4}{R_2+R_4} + \frac{R_1R_3}{R_1+R_3}\right)$$

Now, we kill the current source and find the contribution from the voltage source,

[image]

Using voltage division in the bottom loop (just to show a simple way),

[image]

$$V_Aˊˊ = V_S\frac{R_2}{R_2+R_4}$$

and

$$V_Bˊˊ = -V_S\frac{R_4}{R_2+R_4}$$

Now, to find $V_Cˊˊ$ i will use loop analysis which will let us find all 3 node voltages in one fell swoop.  First, i'll toss out $R_5$ since he is a useless distraction and has zero affect on the rest of the circuit,

[image]

Writing KVL loop equations we normally get simultaneous equations we can solve, but here we can solve for each loop current with just 1 equation each,

Upper loop,

$$-V_S + I_X R_1 + I_X R_3 = 0$$

So,

$$I_X = \frac{V_S}{R_1+R_3}$$

Lower loop,

$$-V_S + I_Y R_2 + I_Y R_4 = 0$$

So,

$$I_Y = \frac{V_S}{R_2+R_4}$$

And thus,

$$V_Aˊˊ = I_Y R_2 = \frac{V_S R_2}{R_2+R_4}$$
$$V_Bˊˊ = -I_Y R_4 = \frac{-V_S R_4}{R_2+R_4}$$

Then finally, we can find the voltage at node C by adding the voltage drop across $R_1$ to the voltage at node A (could have gone the other route from node B as well),

$$V_Cˊˊ = V_Aˊˊ - I_X R_1 = \frac{V_S R_2}{R_2+R_4} -  \frac{V_S R_1}{R_1+R_3}$$

$$V_Cˊˊ = V_S \left(\frac{R_2}{R_2+R_4}-\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_3}\right)$$

Our overall solution is now,

$$V_A = V_Aˊ+ V_Aˊˊ = I_S\frac{R_2R_4}{R_2+R_4}+V_S\frac{R_2}{R_2+R_4}$$
$$V_B = V_Bˊ+ V_Bˊˊ = I_S\frac{R_2R_4}{R_2+R_4}-V_S\frac{R_4}{R_2+R_4}$$
$$V_C = V_Cˊ+ V_Cˊˊ = I_S\left(\frac{R_2R_4}{R_2+R_4}+\frac{R_1R_3}{R_1+R_3}\right) + V_S \left(\frac{R_2}{R_2+R_4}-\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_3}     \right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realize I’m not familiar with superposition. Why does this work? I’m familiar with finding the Thevenin equivalent resistance for a circuit, in which current and voltage sources are “killed” in the same way.

Comment: Superposition works because this is a linear system.  Give  [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_theorem) a read and see if it helps.

Comment: When I know the potentials in A and B, should it then be possible to calculate all the currents in the circuit? I got that A is at a higher potential than B, but the potential at the node above resistor 1 is not known, and this makes calculating the currents there tricky.

Comment: It could be either higher or lower than A, correct?

Comment: Of course, one could just apply superposition again.

Comment: Yes, you need to know that upper nodes voltage too in order to calculate the current in $R_1$ and $R_3$.  You are correct, superposition would again work (or other circuit methods like loop analysis etc.).

Comment: See my answer to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480126/determine-the-voltage-across-the-5-0-%ce%a9-resistor-in-the-drawing/531842#531842) for example on using KVL loop analysis to find currents.

Comment: When one short circuits (removing the voltage source), what happens to the current that splits at the node above A? Does it “burn the wire” between A and B? If the current source would be a voltage source, is it correct that no current would flow since the negative end (the one connected to ground) would essentially be disconnected from the circuit?

Comment: $R_1$ would then be in parallel with $R_4$, and that resulting equivalent resistor would be in series with the parallel combination of $R_2$ and $R_4$.  Redraw the new circuit and you will see how to solve.

Comment: True, however, would there be any current flowing through $R_2$ and $R_4$?

Comment: Yes.  Shorting the voltage source only ties A and B together.  It does not short out either of those resistors - they will each get some current due to the current source.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. In the circuit as attached in the image, is it reasonable to expect that the current flowing through the current source isn’t actually $I_S$?

Comment: Your welcome.  The ideal current source can only produce $I_S$.  It will produce whatever voltage is necessary to drive that current.

Comment: In my calculation I get that the currents that meet at the ground node (below A) don't add up to $I_S$. When opening up the current source, one simply gets the voltage source connected in parallel with $R_1+R_3$ and $R_2+R_4$, and $V_S$ over both of them. In short circuiting the voltage source, one gets what you mentioned in a comment earlier, and in particular, no current flowing between $A$ and $B$ since they are at the same potential, correct?

Comment: In your previous comment; "...$R_1$ would then be in parallel with  $R_4$..." Did you mean $R_3$ instead of $R_4$?

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry, $R_1$ would then be in parallel with $R_3$.  I've gone through the approach as an UPDATE.  See if it helps.

Comment: Superb! Thanks.

Comment: Good deal. You are very welcome.